# Synchronizing overlapping sets of methods

Tags: java, thread-synchronization

Imagine a Java class with three methods:

1. `master()`
2. `foo()`
3. `bar()`

I want to synchronize `master()` and `foo()` and also `master()` and `bar()`, without synchronizing `foo()` and `bar()`. It can be done will a separate lock for every pair of synchronized methods, but my actual code has many more than three methods so I was hoping there's a way to do it without so many lock objects.

Comment: So when `master` is called, `foo` can't be called and when `master` is called, `bar` can't be called?

Comment: Yep. But `foo` and `bar` can be called at the same time (assuming `master` isn't called, of course).

Comment: Are all methods synchronized only against `master()`, or can there be other combinations?

Comment: @BarryFruitman, should multiple threads be able to call `foo()` concurrently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially describing a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). Every two methods are allowed to run simultaneously (a "read lock"), except for `master()`, which excludes all others (a "write lock"):

```
public class MyClass {
    private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock r = rwLock.readLock();
    private final Lock w = rwLock.writeLock();

    public void master() {
        w.lock();
        // do stuff
        w.unlock();
    }

    public void foo() {
        r.lock();
        // do stuff
        r.unlock();
    }

    public void bar() {
        r.lock();
        // do stuff
        r.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this way better because it only uses two locks.

Comment: @aioobe started out with rwLock, and then switched to `rwl` for some reason. Stupid typo, fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Hmm.. Is this really the same thing as what OP is after? If `foo` should be "synchronized" it should mean that only one thread at a time should be able to call `foo`, right?

Comment: @aioobe `foo()` doesn't need to be synchronized on its own; OP wants to block on `foo()` only while `master()` is running.

Comment: You could also use a `StampedLock`, which is similar to a `ReadWriteLock`, but is not reentrant and should have better performance.

Comment: @shmosel, are you sure? OP says *"It can be done will a separate lock for every pair of synchronized methods"*. By this I assume that `foo` would acquire a `fooAndMaster` lock, which would imply that only one thread at a time can call `foo()`.

Comment: @aioobe, valid point, but I'm convinced that OP doesn't actually need to lock on `foo()` itself.

Comment: @shmosel, that may very well be the case. It's just not as obvious to me.

Comment: @aioobe, OP's initial statement "I want to synchronize `master()` and `foo()` and also `master()` and `bar()`" implies that he needs a read/write mutex between `master()` and any other method. The idea of using multiple locks was the only apparent solution to OP, which would avoid locking the entire object at once, though it would have the unwanted side-effect of locking `foo()`. The fact the he marked this answer as correct supports my assertion.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. Please forgive me if my original question was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `synchronized` on any `Object`. So, you can create a separate lock for the methods:

```
public class Lock {
    private final Object master_foo = null;
    private final Object master_bar = null;
    public void master() {
        synchronized(master_foo) {
            synchronized(master_bar) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        synchronized(master_foo) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public void bar() {
        synchronized(master_bar) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said in my original question I was hoping to avoid this approach since I actually have way more than three methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Mureinik's answer, but just for the heck of it, here's another way you can set up read/write synchronization (untested):

```
public class Test {

    private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    public void master() {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        try {
            //...
        } finally {
            semaphore.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
        try {
            //...
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    public void bar() {
        semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
        try {
            //...
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting way of locking methods.